# Why toggle to hide/show not working on table?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to hide/show some html table details when user clics on the master record. i found a nice script here http://blog.movalog.com/a/javascript-toggle-visibility/. So i am trying to make a DIV for a table record set to show/hide all recordset, but seems it doesn't work.

here is my script whit 3 demos record sets, the last one (that is not a table) is the only one working as desired, but i need to implement it on html table record set.

i hope my question be clear.
thanks for help !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == "block")
          e.style.display = "none";
       else
          e.style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
<div class="demoProducts" >
<table id="products" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<thead>
<tr><th class="left">Descripción</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr onclick="toggle_visibility('0101');"><td bgcolor="#CDCDCD" style="font-size:16px"><b>Clic Here to Toggle - MASTER I</b></td></tr>
<div id="0101">
<tr> <td>DETAIL I.1</td></tr>
<tr> <td>DETAIL I.2</td></tr>
<tr> <td>DETAIL I.3</td></tr>
<tr> <td>DETAIL I.4</td></tr>
<tr> <td>DETAIL I.5</td></tr>
</div>

<tr onclick="toggle_visibility('0102');">
<td class="left" bgcolor="#CDCDCD" style="font-size:16px"><b>Clic Here to Toggle - MASTER II</b></td></tr>
<div id="0102">
<tr> <td class="left">DETAIL II.1</td></tr>
<tr> <td class="left">DETAIL II.2</td></tr>
</div>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<a onclick="toggle_visibility('0103');"><bgcolor="#CDCDCD" style="font-size:16px"><b>Click here to toggle</b></a>
<div id="0103">This is Working</div>
```

Comment: Your markup is invalid. Why are you sticking `div` between `tr`? If you check the source of the generated page, you'll notice the browser was smart enough to move those `div` outside the `table`.

Comment: Try changing the div id="0101" to tbody id="0101", you can have multiple tbody's in one table

Comment: ids should not start with numbers

Comment: Thanks for all comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So where to start, my solution gonna work on new browsers because of `html5 data attribute and querySelectorAll` so let's start. I modified your html, i moved your css and javascript. It's true that you can not use `<div>`s between `<tr>`. I've added `class="detail"` for `text-align: left; text-transform: uppercase;`, put table styles too and all 'links/trigger' too. So here my modified html. You can see all the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/36vjdfrx/).

```
<div class="demoProducts">
    <table id="products">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Descripción</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td data-target="i" class="js-hide-siblings trigger">
                    Clic Here to Toggle - MASTER I
                </td>        
            </tr>
            <tr data-detail="i" class="detail">
                <td>detail i.1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-detail="i" class="detail">
                <td>detail i.2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-detail="i" class="detail">
                <td>detail i.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-detail="i" class="detail">
                <td>detail i.4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-detail="i" class="detail">
                <td>detail i.5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-target="ii" class="js-hide-siblings trigger">Clic Here to Toggle - MASTER II</td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-detail="ii" class="detail">
                <td>detail ii.1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-detail="ii" class="detail">
                <td>detail ii.2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<a data-target="working" class="js-hide-siblings trigger">Click here to toggle</a>
<div data-detail="working" class="detail">This is Working</div>
```

My Css :

```
.hide { display: none; }

table {
    border-spacing: 0; /*cellpadding=0*/
    border-collapse: collapse; /*cellspacing="0"*/
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
}

th,
.detail { text-align: left; }

.trigger {
    background-color: #cdcdcd;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.detail { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

And javascript :

```
var hideTrigger = document.querySelectorAll('.js-hide-siblings'),
i,j;

for (i = 0; i < hideTrigger.length; i++) {
    hideTrigger[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var siblings = document.querySelectorAll('[data-detail=' +e.target.getAttribute('data-target')+']');
        /* siblings target all detail tr's with data-detail attribute that is same as triger data-target attribute*/
        e.preventDefault(); /*for links to remove normal click behavior*/
        for (j = 0; j < siblings.length; j++) {
            siblings[j].classList.toggle('hide'); /* if target have hide class i remove it, if not i add */
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it gonna help

Comment: just great. As you can imagine i am new at html, so it's good to know that there are guys like you to guide us. Thanks again, works perfect !